# XlsxWriter in python is entering extra spaces in cells

Tags: python-3.x, csv, xlsxwriter

I'm using xlsxwriter library version 1.2.0 in python 3.7.

I enter a new cell content in Hebrew and another cell in English.
Than when opening the new Excel file in Excel (on windows 10) the two new cells include the strings above but with a space in the end.

I don't understand why this is happening and it prevents me from using other functions in Excel.

Here is the file in Excel:

[image]

I have tried to use the TRIM function in excel on the above cells but it didn't make the space go away.
Also tried ctrl + H to replace the space but it won't find it.

```py
import xlsxwriter
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('hello.xlsx', {'strings_to_numbers': True})
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('sheet1')
worksheet.right_to_left()
worksheet.write(0, 0, 'שלום')
worksheet.write(0, 1, 'hello')
workbook.close()
```

Thnx for the trouble!
Allon

Comment: Are you sure there is indeed a space added? Maybe the cursor is placed some space away from the string because of the [IME settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee418266%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)?

Comment: I'm sure. I had marked it with SHIFT and keyboard arrows. Also it prevents me from filtering rows with dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> XlsxWriter in python is entering extra spaces in cells

XlsxWriter doesn't add spaces to data that it writes, or change it in any way.

> I have tried to use the TRIM function in excel on the above cells but it didn't make the space go away. Also tried ctrl + H to replace the space but it won't find it.

This suggests that there isn't a space at the end since these functions would have changed it. Also, I ran your program and don't see that effect:

[image]

So I suspect you are seeing some other effect of the Excel interface here. What happens if you enter data manually? Do you see the same effect? If you do then it isn't an XlsxWriter issue.

Comment: Thank you for the check and the great library! You are right it happen with all the files... I'm using Excel 2019 16.0.11328.20390 64 bit. I will try open it in older versions.